# Very large zip file (> 50GB) --> ZipException: invalid CEN header

Tags: java, exception, header, zip, large-files

I'm trying to open a ZIP file in JAVA.

The code below works fine except with some large files in which case I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:75)
```

Is there a known bug? Can it be due to higher compression level not supported in JAVA?

Note that I can not use Winzip to uncompress the file, and gzip under Linux gives an error about the data-length (uncompressed file is around 80 GB). I had to use the following workaround to uncompress it:

```
gunzip -S .zip < file.zip > file
```

Any ideas would be very very helpful.

Code:

```
if (file.getExtension().equals("gz")) {
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(name))));
}
else if (file.getExtension().equals("zip")) {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(name); // <-------------------FAILS HERE
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println("ZIP File in the archive:" + zipEntry.getName());
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe Apache Commons Compression can help here? The built-in zip implementation isn't the best as far as I know.

Comment: There is a size limit in default zip implementation. You may find this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6738811/1048330) useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not using Java 7 (which support ZIP64), the issue may be [that java is trying to use the old ZIP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Limits)