# ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Okay, but which file?

Tags: php, zip

I am using ZipArchive on PHP 8.2

I am trying to create a backup for a running website, which has 10 GB of content (images, invoices etc.).

The zipping fails with:

> ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: No such file or directory

I do have 200 GB free disk space on my server, so I don't think that space is the issue. I have read that this issue could be caused because a temporary file was added to the ZipArchive and on zip->close() the file has been removed.

As I have about 48606 files and directories, it would be very helpful for me to understand which file or directory cannot be opened. The zipping works, if I just zip  a handful of folders.

So basically, in the following code, how could I find out which file caused `$zip->close()` to fail?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zipFileName = base_path('example.zip');

if ($zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

    $fileToAdd = base_path('Text');
    file_put_contents($fileToAdd, 'This is some content for the Text file.');

    $zip->addFile($fileToAdd);

    unlink($fileToAdd);

    try{
        $zip->close();
    } catch (\Exception $exception){
        // How to get the missing file base_path('Text')
        // here?
    }
    return 'ZIP archive created successfully!';
}

return 'Failed to create ZIP archive';
```

The exception message from ZipArchive on close is only

> "ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Does your site create any temp files that your code would try to zip?

Comment: Be aware that `ZipArchive` may not support archives larger than 4GB (not sure if it's still true on PHP 8.2). There is also a limit on the number of entries (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11448705/12763954)).

Comment: How about you unlink() _after_ you close()? Actually after you've _successfully_ closed. It seems awfully risky to delete the thing before it has been archived. Also there is no reason that the module could not have been implemented to note and defer the work until the close(), and do it all then. Since you are not in control of that module's implementation, unlinking before closing is incorrect.

Comment: @MarkAdler of course my example can be immediately fixed by moving `unlink()` after `close()`. I just tried to demonstrate my issue. In my backup script for my application, I don't unlink any file. But files get deleted in other side-processes and I need to find out which files these are. Having 50k of files and folders makes it really hard for me to find out where something went wrong.

Comment: @MarkAdler not sure what you mean exactly with "Also there is no reason that the module could not have been implemented to note and defer the work until the close(), and do it all then.". If the module is able to figure out that it cannot open a file, I wonder why it can't tell me which file.

Comment: The Zip extension has its little quirks. For such a backup, I would seriously consider `exec()`ing and external archiver (zip, tar, whatever).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am actually using laravel-backup from spatie for my laravel application https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup - so switching to tar is a litlle tricky. Do you got some reference that Zip extension from PHP is less reliant then tar?

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't reliable, just that sometimes the API design does not allow some things (such as figuring out what file is causing the error).

Answer (score -3):

To find out which file caused `$zip->close()` to fail, you can use the following code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zipFileName = base_path('example.zip');

if ($zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
   $fileToAdd = base_path('Text');
   file_put_contents($fileToAdd, 'This is some content for the Text file.');

   $zip->addFile($fileToAdd);

   unlink($fileToAdd);

   try {
       $zip->close();
   } catch (\Exception $exception) {
       // Get the missing file name
       $missingFileName = $exception->getMessage();

       // Log the missing file name
       \Log::error('Missing file name: ' . $missingFileName);

       // Rethrow the exception
       throw $exception;
   }

   return 'ZIP archive created successfully!';
}

return 'Failed to create ZIP archive';
```

This code will log the missing file name to the Laravel log file. You can then view the log file to see which file caused the error.

Here is an example of a log entry:

> ERROR: Missing file name: /var/www/html/example.com/public/Text This
> log entry tells us that the file Text could not be found when the
> ZipArchive was closed.

Once you have identified the missing file, you can try to resolve the issue. For example, you may need to add the file to the ZipArchive before you close it, or you may need to create the file if it does not exist.

In your case, it is possible that the file Text is being deleted before the ZipArchive is closed. To resolve this issue, you can try to move the file to a different location before you close the ZipArchive.

Here is an example of how to move the file:

```
$oldFileName = base_path('Text');
$newFileName = base_path('Temp/Text');

rename($oldFileName, $newFileName);

$zip->addFile($newFileName);

unlink($newFileName);

$zip->close();
```

This code will move the file Text to the Temp directory before it is added to the ZipArchive. Once the file has been added to the ZipArchive, it will be moved back to its original location.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That does not work. The exception message is just "ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Adam This looks like a generated answer.

Comment: "_This code will log the missing file name to the Laravel log file_" Laravel?

Comment: @brombeer Maybe he knew because I am using "base_path" in my script, which is a laravel helper